# How do you cook corn kernels on BBQ?

Tags: barbecue, corn

I recently had some BBQ corn where the corn was in individual kernels. I'm wondering how this would be done on a BBQ... would you [grill the corn on the cob](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/how-do-you-cook-corn-on-the-cob-on-bbq), then cut the kernels off? Or would you do it the other way around? If so, in what would you cook the kernels?

Must I use raw corn or can I use corn kernels from a can?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use raw corn. You can either grill it on the cob, or use a [mesh grill roasting pan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003HFYZ4C).

Answer (score 4):

You would indeed want to leave the kernels on the corn and grill it according to the link you cited.

Answer (score 1):

When I use roasted corn kernels in recipes and have access to grilling weather, I find it ideal to pre-soak the heads of corn in water for about 20-40 minutes then grill, husk intact, for about 25-35. Once they are cooked, take off the husk, cut of the kernels with a knife going vertically from stem to tip.

You can also freeze corn prepared this way and it makes for a nice taste of summer when you add them to food in February.

Comment: ...For extra points in the smoky department rub the kernels with paprika between soak and grill then replace the husk.

Comment: try grilling husk and silk off with tons of butter slathered on some time.  Wonderful.

Comment: @justkt for eating off the cob i absolutely agree, but for cooking in BBQ i like the smokiness the husk adds

Answer (score 1):

Roasted Corn in January Snow:

If you do not have access to a grill, like during winter time, my preferred method for roasting corn without the fire is to use a skillet and about 1 teaspoon **maybe** of olive/peanut oil and a teaspoon of paprika.

Basically, heat the oil until it is good and hot and coats the bottom of the skillet smoothly. Drop the paprika (or chili powder, ancho powder, etc) in the bottom of the pan, let it roast for about 30-60 seconds pushing it around with a spatula a bit, add the corn from a can (*drained*), and burn the corn a bit (tossing it with the spatula).

Comment: Yes, this is an excellent way to cook corn.  But this is not really a direct answer to the original question.

Comment: @rsch right, i was providing an additional method of simulating the BBQ'd corn, basically because not everyone has grill access all year and because not everyone has fresh corn all year