# Putting "precooked corn on the cob" on the barbeque?

Tags: grilling

I bought 4 corn on the cob today, plasticwrapped, no husk left, cleaned and everything.

These have a sticker saying "precooked".

Should I assume that I can just place them directly on the barbeque, or should I still put them in water a while before?

Comment: I personally find that most corn do not even require soaking. Fresh corn can just go directly on the grill wrapped in some foil. Corn is so adjusting, that the seasonings can be added before or after grilling.

Comment: I wouldn't soak them ... see [my answer from a previous question for different methods](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1542/67).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting corn in water only makes sense if it is still in the husk, as that will keep the husks from burning. Soaking precooked de-husked corn would make no difference to you. You can barbecue it, but as it is precooked I'd keep the cooking time down to a couple of minutes, just long enough to heat it up and get a bit of color on it. Any more and it may be overcooked.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll experiment but I'll definitely try it like you say the first time around :)