# How can one cook corn on an open grill?

Tags: corn, camping, grill

I’ll be camping with limited access to water. I have a grill in the outside kitchen, however this grill doesn’t have a cover. Is it possible to grill corn on the cob on a cooking surface without a cover? If so, how?

Comment: I knew I had answered this question before: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1542/67

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the corn still in the husk ?

Do you have aluminium foil ?

Keep the corn in the husk and roast until cooked; it's better to remove some of the leaves and dip them in water to add some moisture to the corn before putting on the grill.

If you have aluminium foil, you can either keep the corn as is and wrap in foil, or remove the husk and wrap in foil and put on grill until cooked.

If your grill is really hot, you can finish the corn to add some color.

Comment: I disagree with the removal of leaves and adding water.  There is plenty of water in the leaves of fresh corn and more leaves are better.  The outer leaves will dry and burn but protect the inner leaves and kernels from the same.  This is my favorite way to cook corn on the cob.  It's perfect every time.

Comment: I even cook corn like this in the oven.  And to me is seems the removal of the silk is easier after it has been cooked.

Comment: @JGinSD Yes and no.  The silk comes off easily but the main challenge with this approach is that husking hot corn can be a little painful.  I use a pair of cheap welding gloves but you can do it with bare hands, if you are quick.

Comment: @JimmyJames you just have to be careful

Answer (score 16):

Even husked corn can be nicely roasted on an open grill.  Use gentle heat, turning frequently until the kernels are golden.  Some kernels will be darker, even charred a bit, but I find that enjoyable.

Comment: That’s how I do it.  I husk it, but I try to leave the stem part intact, as I can leave that part sticking off the edge as a handle.  Every so often, I give it maybe 1/5 of a turn.  If you start to hear popping, turn it, and try to give it a little less time before the next turn

Comment: @Joe I prefer tongs :-)....but I do enjoy a grilled ear or two!

Answer (score 0):

While keeping it wrapped (foil or husk) is preferable, you certainly can throw pre-prepared corn on the cob straight onto your grill. Just be aware it may cook extremely quickly so needs rotation.
It is also likely to get quite a char but some people like that.